# Should it be supported to store a pandas dataframe in another pandas dataframe? I can no longer display such data frames. Is this a bug?

Tags: python, pandas

I have existing code where I found it useful to use a pandas data frame to store other data frames and this was working nicely in pandas 0.10.1 but it is no longer possible to display such data frames using pandas 0.12.0. Yet it is still possible to store to and retrieve from such data frames. Is this a Bug or am I doing something wrong?

Illustrative example:

Working in 0.10.1:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'0.10.1'
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[3, 4, 5]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([df1, df1+10])
>>> df2[0][0]
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
>>> df2[0][1]
    a   b
0  11  13
1  12  14
2  13  15
>>> df2
        0
0  [a, b]
1  [a, b]
>>>
```

And not working in pandas 0.12.0:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> pd.__version__
'0.12.0'
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[3, 4, 5]})
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame([df1, df1+10])
>>> df2[0][0]
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
>>> df2[0][1]
    a   b
0  11  13
1  12  14
2  13  15
>>> df2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 40, in __repr__
    return str(self)
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 20, in __str__
    return self.__bytes__()
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 32, in __bytes__
    return self.__unicode__().encode(encoding, 'replace')
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 665, in __unicode__
    fits_horizontal = self._repr_fits_horizontal_()
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 646, in _repr_fits_horizontal_
    d.to_string(buf=buf)
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1556, in to_string
    formatter.to_string()
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 294, in to_string
    strcols = self._to_str_columns()
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 247, in _to_str_columns
    fmt_values = self._format_col(i)
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 398, in _format_col
    space=self.col_space)
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 1366, in format_array
    return fmt_obj.get_result()
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 1382, in get_result
    fmt_values = self._format_strings()
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 1418, in _format_strings
    fmt_values.append(' %s' % _format(v))
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 1404, in _format
    return '%s' % formatter(x)
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/format.py", line 1394, in <lambda>
    formatter = (lambda x: com.pprint_thing(x, escape_chars=('\t', '\r', '\n'))) \
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 2059, in pprint_thing
    quote_strings=quote_strings)
  File "/home/data/Local/Envs/latest/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 1963, in _pprint_seq
    r.append(pprint_thing(next(s), _nest_lvl + 1, **kwds))
StopIteration
```

Comment: it is a bug: in pandas code len(df1) is going to return 3 that is the length of the df1 index, but then the code iterates on df1 3 times through the for loop inside code. However the iterator will return the columns names 'a' and 'b' and this length is 2, so the third iteration raises a StopIteration

Comment: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/5324 already posted by faster than light pandas developer friends

Comment: this is a 'bug', so fixing it for 0.13, see [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/5325), but in general this is not a good idea. as you don't get any performance benefit from doing this.

Comment: @Jeff I'm going again marketing for Panel-not-be-fifth-wheel in pandas

Comment: @Boud its pretty good in 0.13.....(and this problem of course should use it)...but it also supports this

Comment: @Boud I'll join you on the crusade for Panels. I've had the need to start using them, and for a certain kind of problem they're ideal.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response by all. This fix will save me a lot of pain.

Comment: @TomAugspurger pls file an issue for missing functionaility. Already have a nice fix for Panel.apply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Note that this has been depracated as of Pandas 0.25.0.

Apart from the bug mentioned in the comments, you should consider using a [`Panel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#panel) when your intuition or model leads you to create a dataframe of dataframes.

```
pd.Panel({0:df1, 1:df1+10})
Out[2]: 
<class 'pandas.core.panel.Panel'>
Dimensions: 2 (items) x 3 (major_axis) x 2 (minor_axis)
Items axis: 0 to 1
Major_axis axis: 0 to 2
Minor_axis axis: a to b
```

You can then do what to accomplish in your code above:

```
p[0]
Out[4]: 
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  5

p[1]
Out[5]: 
    a   b
0  11  13
1  12  14
2  13  15
```

But if need, you also have access to other dimension manipulations more easily:

```
p.minor_xs('a')
Out[6]: 
   0   1
0  1  11
1  2  12
2  3  13
```

Comment: Thanks Bond. Indeed a panel is best used in this case it was just chosen as the most straightforward way of showing what was happening. My use case for embedded pandas objects is where I wish to create a table with related information and have the very nice feature of labelled indexing yet some of the entries are simply floats some are series and some are data frames (or potentially panels all though panels has not arisen yet for me).  This normally ends up being type grouped by column but not necessarily. Also missing embedded objects are then stored as a single NaN.

Answer (score 0):

I underline Boud's answer. However, an alternative to using `panel` is a normal `DataFrame` with a MultiIndex. This is in the object logic not as clean as a panel, but since `panel` has a lot of features not (yet?) implemented, it is valuable alternative.